# ServiceStack server-sent events - parameterized channels?

Tags: servicestack, server-sent-events

If I'm building something like a real time stock update page and want to send the updates via SSE - is the best practice to embed any parameters you need for the service (the stock symbol) as part of the channel name? Something like

```
var msgSrc = new EventSource('http://localhost/dvsvc/event-stream?channels=stockupdates-MSFT');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that's fine, although I'd make the name shorter as if a user wants to subscribe to multiple stocks they'd need to all be included so i'd be inclined to just use the stock ticker, e.g:

```
 /event-stream?channels=MSFT,GOOG,AMZN,FB,AAPL,IBM,INTC
```